# UserControl glitch

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework

При загрузке формы выполняю следующий код:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pw = new PleaseWait();
    this.Controls.Add(pw);
    pw.BringToFront();
    pw.Visible = false;
}
```

чтобы добавить нижеследующий элемент управления.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Во время выполнения программы в нужный момент выполняю `pw.Visible = true`, но вместо элемента выше, получаю следующее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Элемент загружается неполностью, видна часть формы, которая под ним. Как фиксить понятия не имею.
Если делать элемент видимым при загрузке формы, то он отрисовывается нормально.

Comment: "нужный момент выполняю pw.Visible = true" - что это за момент? Это обработчик события GUI или просто какой-то код в каком-то потоке (в каком?)  Приведите лучше соответствующий метод из вашего кода.